# getting my arrraylist into a pdf file with java

Tags: java, arraylist, pdfbox

I have a problem getting printing all the elements of my ArrayList into a pdf file using PDFbox. The problem is that the pdf file generated by the program does not contain all the elements of the ArrayList. I do not understand why, it may be because all the elements of the ArrayList would not fit on one page but adding pages to the pdf did not solve the problem. Here is an excerpt of my code:

```
public PDPageContentStream gettextperpage(PDDocument document, PDPageContentStream contentStream, ArrayList<Component> In, int startind) {
    int ht=740;

    try {
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(60,ht);

            int nbel=0;

            if (startind/13==8) {
                nbel=8;
            }
            else {
                nbel=13;
            }
            System.out.println(nbel);
            for(int i=0; i<nbel;i++)
            {   
                int ind=startind+i;
                Component cp=In.get(ind);
                //contentStream.beginText(); 
                contentStream.showText(cp.toString());

                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0,-LINE_HEIGHT-30);

                //contentStream.endText(); 


            }
            //contentStream.showText( "Company:"+_asc +"  "+_desc);
            contentStream.endText();

            for (int i=0; i<13; i++)
            {
                PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("4056182.jpg", document);
                contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 550, ht-40,40,40);
                ht-=50;
            }

            contentStream.close();
        }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contentStream;       

}
public void getoutputpdf(PDDocument document,ArrayList<Component> In) {

    for (int k=0; k<9; k++) {

        try {


            System.out.println(k);

            // Create a new blank page and add it to the document
            PDPage Page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage( Page );



            // Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, Page);
            contentStream=gettextperpage(document,contentStream,In,13*k);
            // Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"





            // Save the newly created document
            document.save("testtot.pdf");

            // finally make sure that the document is properly
            // closed.

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Never, never, **NEVER** name an `ArrayList` as List.... `List` is an interface that `ArrayList` implements, so what you are essentially doing is confusing the compiler, yourself and us by naming a variable `List`.  Please rename the `ArrayList` to something more relevant to the functionality of the code...

Comment: Thanks. Renamed the ArrayList to comp_list but that does not solve the problem.

Comment: I wasn't saying that that would solve your problem.  Have you tried just writing something arbitrary to the PDF? maybe just "Hello World" just for testing.  If that works, limit your `for-loop` to only print maybe 3 items. `for(int i=0;i<3;i++)`.  This will help you to determine if it just is running off the page or if your method of printing is incorrect

Comment: I don't know the intricacies of the library you're using, but what is `height` doing?  You increment it by 10 each iteration and it doesn't seem to be used anywhere after that

Comment: @m_h *"it may be because all the elements of the ArrayList would not fit on one page but adding pages to the pdf did not solve the problem."* - If you assume that you need more than one page, why do you show us the code for putting everything on one page? I assume you did something wrong in the way you added additional pages or continued your list on the next page. But as you did not show that code, I can merely guess.

Comment: Good point. But for some reason I never get more than 5 elements in the pdf file whereas there are many more elements in the ArrayList. These are printed correctly in the console.

Comment: @mki I removed the extra code to add more pages to the pdf file since it just resulted in two blank pages in the pdf apart from the first one which had  5 elements on it.

Comment: @CraigR8806 Incrementing the height variable was not useful , so I removed that line. It actually changed the distance between rows which was not what I wanted.

Comment: What is the value of LINE_HEIGHT?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr The constant was defined before in the code: private static final float LINE_HEIGHT = 20;

Comment: This means that the next lines will appear on 720, 740, 760, etc. The height of an A4 page is about 800. And no, PDFBox won't automatically write to a next page. You have to program this yourself. HTH... I'm not eben sure if I've understood the question.

Comment: @m_h *`LINE_HEIGHT = 20;`* - i.e. you start pretty high on the page (y = 700) and from there move *upwards* 20 units per entry. Ok. Then there is no wonder only about 5 elements fit...

Comment: @mki Thanks a lot, that solves part of the problem.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Thank you for this info.  After modifying the code, I managed to fill the page with objects of the ArrayList. I will need to add pages to the pdf and fill them too until there are no more elements in the ArrayList

Comment: @m_h what problem is left now?

Comment: @TilmanHausherr I need to specify the current page on which the program should print in order to print out the whole ArrayList because it won't all fit on one page.

Comment: Does this mean you need code that creates a new page and sets the position to start when the max size is reached?

Comment: That's right. Haven't figured how to do that yet.

Comment: Actually, I just need to add a new page to the document once I have filled up the first page, then create a new content stream and associate with that new page. Thanks.

Comment: @m_h Is there still a problem with the code? Or does it work fine now? In the latter case you should not have edited the code in the question but instead you should have created an answer with the fixed code (and a few words explaining the fixes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved. Taking all the comments into consideration, I came up with a solution to print the contents of the ArrayList on many pages in a pdf.

```
public void gettextperpage(PDDocument document, PDPageContentStream contentStream, ArrayList<Component> In, int startind) {
    int ht=740;
    int h=0;
    try {
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(60,ht);

            int nbel=0;

            if (startind/13==8) {
                nbel=8;
                h=-280;
            }
            else {
                nbel=13;
                h=-10;
            }
            //System.out.println(nbel);
            for(int i=0; i<nbel;i++)
            {   
                int ind=startind+i;
                Component cp=In.get(ind);
                //contentStream.beginText(); 
                contentStream.showText(cp.toString());

                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0,-LINE_HEIGHT-30);

                //contentStream.endText(); 
            }
            //contentStream.showText( "Company:"+_asc +"  "+_desc);
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(250,h);
            contentStream.showText(Integer.toString((startind+13)/13));
            contentStream.endText();

            for (int i=0; i<nbel; i++)
            {
                int ind=startind+i;
                Component cp=In.get(ind);
                if (!cp.getimage().isEmpty()) {
                    String imagepath="photospieces/"+cp.getimage();
                    PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagepath, document);
                    contentStream.drawImage(pdImage, 550, ht-40,40,40);

                }
                ht-=50;
            }
            contentStream.close();
        }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return contentStream;       
}

public void getoutputpdf(PDDocument document,ArrayList<Component> In) {
    headerpage(document);
    for (int k=0; k<9; k++) {
        try {
            //System.out.println(k);

            // Create a new blank page and add it to the document
            PDPage Page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage( Page );

            // Start a new content stream which will "hold" the to be created content
            PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, Page);
            contentStream=gettextperpage(document,contentStream,In,13*k);
            // Define a text content stream using the selected font, moving the cursor and drawing the text "Hello World"
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The function gettextperpage writes a chunk of the arraylist on one page of the pdf. One of the arguments of the function determines which chunk of the arraylist will be written on the page. 
The function getoutputpdf applies the function gettextperpage on different parts of the arraylist in order to produce the multiple pages of the pdf file.